# JMeter using JSON extracted data with formatting characters in an http request

Tags: json, jmeter

In JMeter, I have one http request that brings back some data.  I am using the JSON Extrator post-processor element to extract the data for 'description'.  The JSON response looks like this:

```
{
  "status": "OK",
  "results": [
{
  "id": "123",
  "name": "My Store",
  "description": "<TEXTFORMAT LEADING="2"><LI><FONT FACE="Verdana" SIZE="11" COLOR="#555555" LETTERSPACING="0" KERNING="0">List value as &quot;Puppies&quot; and &quot;Kittens&quot; where appropriate to maximize the cuteness factor. <FONT COLOR="#0B333C"></FONT></FONT></LI></TEXTFORMAT><TEXTFORMAT LEADING="2"><LI><FONT FACE="Verdana" SIZE="11" COLOR="#555555" LETTERSPACING="0" KERNING="0">Before using puppies check the list (i.e. a pet-list). This list should be good. <FONT COLOR="#0B333C"></FONT></FONT></LI></TEXTFORMAT><TEXTFORMAT LEADING="2"><LI><FONT FACE="Verdana" SIZE="11" COLOR="#555555" LETTERSPACING="0" KERNING="0">Before check the list.<FONT COLOR="#0B333C"></FONT></FONT></LI></TEXTFORMAT>"
}
  ]
}
```

Then I use this extracted value in another POST request and it is saying the JSON is invalid.  I'm almost positive it has to do with all the formatting special characters.  Is there a secret to using the JSON extractor so it can post the special characters?  Should I do some post post process where I add escape chars to the data in the extracted data?

Comment: The data use show is XML not JSON.Please explain what you want to get

Comment: could you explain what are you doing with extracted value?

Comment: I want to extract the 'description' with all the text formatting that I got from a GET HTTP Request and put it into a POST HTTP Request with a JSON payload.  The POST says it's invalid JSON